# Which mark to use

Tags: vim

I'm going through http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/04.html
and the exercise wants me to make  in normal mode upcase the current word.

I did:

```
nnoremap <c-u> mmgUaw`m<esc>
```

and I'm using a mark (the m mark) to prevent the cursor from moving.

I don't like this solution because what should be a purely functional change ends up changing the global state of vim (by setting up a mark).

Is there a better way to do this, or is there a mark (or a set of marks) that should only be used by commands/mappings and not interactively (because commands/mappings change it/them)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the best I came up with:

```
nnoremap <c-u> i<esc>guiw`^
```

to utilize the last position of the cursor in insert mode.

Answer (score 1):

The [example](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tips.html#restore-position) from the Vim help uses the `s` register itself, so your approach isn't necessarily a bad one (i.e. if the mapping is just for your own use then you can just pick a register you don't use for anything else).

Having said that, the special backtick (`) register might be better here, since it's local to the buffer and is meant to store the most recent jump point anyway.

Comment: Mathew is correct the `'` mark is typically used for such things. However it is a common behavior to move the cursor to the start of a "change". e.g. `gUiw`, `yiw`, `>>`,  etc.  So saving the cursor position is actually a bit out of the ordinary.